# fitBounds on points after feature selection

Tags: leaflet, carto

I am trying to follow some of the examples I have found here and in Google Groups about fitBounds for points. Most of the examples are for polygons and don't seem to work for points.  I think I've tried just about every combo of syntax that generally looks like the following:

```
 var sql = cartodb.SQL({ user: 'username' });
 
 //feature selection buttons:
 $('.button').click(function(e, latlon, lat, lng, pxPos, data, layer) {
   
   $('.button').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
   
   //I think I need to include an sql statement with lat and lon to get bounds, but I could be wrong:
   //sql.execute("SELECT cartodb_id, name, ST_X(the_geom) lon, ST_Y(the_geom) lat FROM table_name WHERE name = " + $(this).attr('selected'), function(ret) {

   var swLat = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat,
       swLon = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng,
       neLat = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat,
       neLon = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng,

       //fitBounds works with manual inputs (below)
       southWest = L.latLng(40.56, -112.05),
       northEast = L.latLng(40.77, -111.8),
       
       //...**but not with this part**
       //southWest = L.latLng(swLat, swLon),
       //northEast = L.latLng(neLat, neLon),

       bounds =  L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast),
   
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   
   LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')] ();

 });
```

How do I do fitBounds for points and not polygons?

Here is the jsbin, annotated to the best of my ability: http://jsbin.com/hunovumu/38/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less of a Leaflet issue than a CartoDB one. In your code you are adding a CartoDB layer to your Leaflet map, then interacting with CartoDB to filter the features the layer shows.

The short answer is: you need to **ask CartoDB for the bounds**. Leaflet doesn't know much about the CartoDB layer, especially when it comes to the features CartoDB is showing.

The longer answer is:

1. Get the bounds from CartoDB. There are a few ways to do this, but the easiest is likely to use [`sql.getBounds()`](http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-6-2). This will looks something like:

   ```
   var sql = new cartodb.SQL({ user: 'tbushman' });
   sql.getBounds(YOUR_QUERY).done(function(bounds) {
       // TODO Set Leaflet's bounds here
   });
   ```

   Where `YOUR_QUERY` is whatever SQL query you used to filter your layer. For example, looking in your code, one of them is:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM full_uu_tb WHERE type = 'Health and Ability'
   ```
2. Now set your Leaflet map's bounds (on the `TODO` line above). This should be as simple as what you already have in the code above:

   ```
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   ```
3. Get rid of most of the bounds-handling code you have above, everything between (but not including) `$(this).addClass('selected');` and `LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')] ();`

Finally, the `LayerActions` object in your full code is a nice way of separating the various SQL queries from the rest of the code. The only problem is that it is a bit redundant and you're going to need to get the actual SQL query in order to get the bounds. I would recommend storing *only* the SQL queries this way and moving the rest into `$('.button').click(...)`.